# MFA and SSO issue

Tags: single-sign-on, mfa

we have had SSO setup for Salesforce a while now and recently had to setup MFA as it was being auto enabled by Salesforce, but now the users are asked to download the authenticator app, Is there something else that was needed as I thought it would let us in as normal without downloading the Salesforce authenticator app.

Many thanks in advance for your help on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If users are directly logging in from the SFDC UX and MFA is enabled, then they need to provide some sort of additional factor for verification. This can be:

- A 6 digit code generated by an authenticator app (including SFDC's own authenticator app or any number of 3rd party authenticator apps)
- Some sort of security keys
- Built-in authenticator like TouchId or Windows Hello

This is all covered in the [MFA FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388806&type=1) and especially in the section entitled `Which verification methods satisfy the MFA requirement?`

If users access SFDC via an SSO solution, then the SSO solution provides the additional factor (probably using the same set of items listed above)

***Postscript based on your comments***

Note that you can also do the following

- [Disable login from the UX](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_enforce_sso_login.htm&type=5)
- Expose your Identity Provider as a login option on the login.salesforce.com page; `Setup | My Domain | Authentication Configuration`

Also verify that if user is not logged in and they click a link to a SFDC page, that SFDC redirects this request to the IdP for a SAML assertion. This requires your Single Signon Configuration to properly point at the IdP (see `Identity Provider Login URL`)

Comment: Thank you - the users already use SSO and it's been working fine until we enabled MFA, now it's asking them to use the app authenticator as well as SSO, it's odd as some Profiles let you log straight in using the SSO but other require app as well, this is what's confusing me, maybe there's setting in Session Security that I am missing, or something on profile.

Comment: So currently we have just 4 users in our org that are being asked to use the app, all the others it lets them straight in with SSO.

Comment: The only difference I can see in login history is the login type, the user that can access has SSO in there and the ones that require the app for login have Application.

Comment: login type Application means they logged in from the UX.  Perhaps your Single Signon Configuration is not redirecting them to the IdP?  Are you exposing the IdP login options on the login screen - see `Setup | My Domain | Authentication Configuration`. There's also a setting to disable login from the UX

Comment: Thank you for that, sounds like I may be able to sort it now.

Comment: great - when you do, as a service to the community, mark the answer (or a better one if it arises) as accepted (use the check mark)